# Drawing an image from an array of "Sprites" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, sprite

So I'm making a game in JavaScript and I'm trying to place "Sprites" I've defined inside an array.

This is what my Sprite object looks like

```
function Sprite(imgsrc)
{
 this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;
 this.velocity_xr = 0;
 this.velocity_xl = 0;
 this.velocity_yu = 0;
 this.velocity_yd = 0;
 this.velocity_x = 0;
 this.velocity_y = 0;
 this.IMG = new Image();
 this.IMG.src = imgsrc;
 this.visible = false;
}
```

So I've done this:

```
var buttons = [];
var b = new Sprite("https://i.imgur.com/qDH38qs.png");
buttons.push(b):
```

And then tried to draw it using this line, with no success.

```
ctx.drawImage(bullets[0].IMG,300,300);
```

However, this works:

```
ctx.drawImage(b.IMG,300,300);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ – that `bullets` and `buttons` are two completely different things …?

Comment: um.. is it buttons or bullets?

Comment: Err... I'm an idiot for failing to notice that repeatedly while trying to understand why it wouldn't work. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: Where is the array _bullet_ initialized? Instead of _bullet[0].IMG_ try _buttons[0].IMG_ ...